# Excel: match column and find next value after a given date

Tags: excel, date, match

I am struggling with a formula and need help.

I have two tables:
Table 1 - containing columns'.

"Cust_ID" and "Enrolled date"

Table 2 -containing

"Cust_ID" and "Invoice_date"

i need to match cust_ID and return the next date from invoice date column after enrolled date.

I used following formula but it didn't really worked for me.

=INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(A4,$F$2:$F$13,-1))

Please help.

[image]

Comment: I think... If you sort your right table on invoice date with the "highest" date on top you can use vlookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to sort your data then you will need an Array formula like this:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$13,MATCH(MIN(IF(($G$2:$G$13>=B2)*($F$2:$F$13=A2),$G$2:$G$13-B2)),IF(($G$2:$G$13>=B2)*($F$2:$F$13=A2),$G$2:$G$13-B2),0))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when editing edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Click on C2.  Put the formula in the formula bar.  Click Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Wow! that's a really big formula but it worked. Thanks a lot. I will spend some time understanding it.