# Excel Multi Criteria Lookup also based on current date

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to find a solution to an Excel problem that I'm having.

It's a simple equation I thought but turns out it's not so much.

One sheet:

```
Column A: Dates
Column B: Serial Numbers
Column C: Maint Status of that Serial Number.
```

On the summary sheet I need the most current status of column B to be displayed.
This formula works to get the first status but not the most current.

```
=INDEX('Daily Flight Stats'!B3:C9,MATCH(B3,'Daily Flight Stats'!B3:B9,0),2)
```

I just can't get it to look at `<=` the current date and return the status that was most currently entered for the equipment. any help would be great.

Comment: Sort your data descending on column A and it will return the most current.

Comment: Yes sir, but the way this sheet is created is IAW a regulation on tracking this equipment.  It's a running log starting in 2015 running thru 2020 an I must have it displayed oldest to newest.  Is there an equation that will sort just for purposes of calculations without effecting the way the data appears?

Comment: You will need an array formula. See my answer here for guidance.  Try to manipulate that one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186700/excel-match-column-and-find-next-value-after-a-given-date/41186913#41186913

Comment: OMG, Amazing Array.... No way Im figuring that out for my case.  I get a lot of it but not sure what to do for my specific.  Ill start trying some arrays but I doubt Ill have much luck.  So far this is what I have but still not much luck as an array. =INDEX('Daily Flight Stats'!B3:C9,MATCH(B4,MIN((A3:A9<=TODAY()),'Daily Flight Stats'!B4:C9,0),2))  I just don't understand them well yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but I have the solution for it. First, see screenshot of the sample data:

[image]

With this data in order to get the current status (`Column F`), we have to use the following ARRAY Formula for cell `F4`:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$14,MATCH(1,(E4=$B$2:$B$14)*($A$2:$A$14=MAX(IF($B$2:$B$14=E4,$A$2:$A$14,0))),0))
```

As is an ARRAY Formula, needs to be confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` instead of `ENTER`. Then the formula can be dragged down.